# How to batch split a big wav file in multiple files with loop point?

Tags: samples, batch-processing

Windows user here :)

I own an Ensoniq SQ1, and i dumped the wavetable ROMs, obtaining a single WAV file containing all the "waveforms" the synth uses for its OSCs.
I also have a spreadsheet table defining the Waveform names, rootkey, and start/loop/end sample number.

Now i need to "automagically" split that big single wav file obtaing one WAV file for each waveform with loop point (and rootkey? can a wav file containt this info?) included, so i can use that waveforms in modern Samplers (or ROMplers) VSTs.

What could i use to obtain this result? As i said, i'm a Windows user. I have access to a friend's PC with Soundforge installed (which is where i checked the loop points exporting my table to a Region file), otherwise i'd need to stay on freeware software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**sox**](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage). If you are using Windows, then you can install [**MobaXterm**](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) on your computer. Then install the sox using: `apt-get install sox`.

Invoking sox is very simple, just provide the start time and the duration to cut. For 2 minute chunk starting at 5m 32s you get:

```
sox in.wav out.wav trim 5:32 2:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standardised way to export the loop point and root key, so other samplers/romplers will understand.

You could add the start/stop points(in samples) to the Regions List in Sound Forge manually, or use the script feature to read the info from the table if you wish, then export the regions. You could then, for each file edit the loop point with the Loop Tuner window. The loop points will be saved as metadata. But I don't know how you could get a sam/rompler to understand the loop points and use them correctly.

I have found an interesting site for you. Check it out.

http://www.buchty.net/ensoniq/

A guy on there has cut up a dump from a SQ-80, Maybe you could get some info off him.

Good luck.